# javascript chart.js remove last point

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a linechart from chart.js. I'd like to remove the last point, but the method removeData() has no arguments for a Line chart, while for a polar chart, it does support removeData(atIndex). So for a line chart, the removeData() only removes the first point by default.

How can I remove only the last point without having to remove all data first?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own by looking at the source code for `removeData` - just use `pop` instead of `shift`

```
myChart.removeLastPoint = function() {
  this.scale.xLabels.pop();
  this.scale.valuesCount--;
  this.scale.fit();

  Chart.helpers.each(this.datasets,function(dataset){
    dataset.points.pop();
  },myChart);

  this.update();   
}
```

where `myChart` is your chart object.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/38gxavst/

Comment: cheers! glad it helped. You might want to mark this as the answer once you're sure it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this doesn't work, first time using JSFiddle but seems to work when I run it locally:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78ns03cv/)

So what i'm doing here is i'm creating the initial chart, then when I click the remove button it gets the current data and assigns it to a variable, pops off the last value and then assigns it back to the chart's data before running the update function.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<button onclick="removeLast()">
Remove
</button>
```

JS:

```
var options = {};

var currData = {
                labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Number of beers drunk in the last week",
                        data: [5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 8, 3]
                    }
]}

removeLast = function() {
    dataArray = currData.datasets[0].data;
    dataArray.pop();
  console.log(dataArray);
    currData.datasets[0].data = dataArray;
  console.log(currData.datasets[0].data)
    myLineChart.update();
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(currData);
```

This should work in both release version and the beta.